# Superimpose 2 barplots with ggplot and 2 filters

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data frame that has data grouped by session and condition. I want to plot session vs #hits, colored by condition and filtered by sex.

This is a sample of my data:

```
library(tidyverse)

    df <- tribble(
        ~session, ~condition, ~sex, ~Obs_target_hits_mean 
        , 0          , 1       , "F"    , 3
        , 1          , 2       , "F"    , 3
        , 2          , 1       , "F"    , 1
        , 3          , 1       , "F"    , 2
        , 0          , 3       , "M"    , 4
        , 1          , 2       , "M"    , 1
        , 2          , 2       , "M"    , 1
        , 3          , 3       , "M"    , 1
        , 0          , 1       , "M"    , 2
        , 1          , 1       , "M"    , 3
    )
```

This is my code but the figure looks weird. Ideally, I would like plots that would be similar to MATLAB's hold function

```
df1 <- df %>% filter(sex=="F")
df2 <- df %>% filter(sex=="M")
ggplot() + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", data = df1, aes(x = df1$session, y = 
         df1$obs_target_hits_mean), fill = df1$condition) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", data = df2, aes(x = df2$session, y = 
         df2$obs_target_hits_mean), color= df2$condition, alpha = 0.5)
```

The figures for M and Female do not look distinct. What should I do?

Thanks,
Trishna

Comment: `df1$obs_target_hits_mean` does not exist in your dataframe.

Comment: Sorry yes, the column name got edited out, I have modified my response to include it. The column hits refers to target_hits_mean

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know, what the expected result is supposed to be, but is this helping?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~session, ~condition, ~sex, ~hits
    , 0          , 1       , "F"    , 3
    , 1          , 2       , "F"    , 3
    , 2          , 1       , "F"    , 1
    , 3          , 1       , "F"    , 2
    , 0          , 3       , "M"    , 4
    , 1          , 2       , "M"    , 1
    , 2          , 2       , "M"    , 1
    , 3          , 3       , "M"    , 1
    , 0          , 1       , "M"    , 2
    , 1          , 1       , "M"    , 3
)

df %>%
    group_by(session, condition, sex) %>%
    summarise(obs_target_hits_mean = mean(hits)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(session, obs_target_hits_mean, fill = factor(condition))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    facet_grid(. ~ sex)
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly, what I want is a plot of session versus observed target hits on the same figure, not layed side by side but rather on top of each other so I can tell the difference across sessions and conditions for different sexes.